# Why is it correct to say "He came and said something to me" but not "He came and said to me something"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, prepositional-objects, dative-alternation

This question was just posed to me and I couldn't give a clear answer beyond that the second just feels wrong and one would generally use a direct or indirect quotation, as in "he came and said to me that he can't come." However, I'm led to believe that it's just a matter of usage, as it feels OK to say "He came and said to me something I'll never forget," or something along those lines.

Is this incorrect or just a matter of usage?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think all verbs that connect with two nouns, one with a preposition and one without naturally take the one without first, just to avoid sticking two nouns together. "took X from Y", "broke X away from Y", "combined X with Y" etc. This may be reversed if you want to emphasize the subject not accompanied by the preposition: "Attach to X Y (but not Z!)"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Say* is a bitransitive verb, which means it takes **two** object phrases.

One is the person addressed (the Indirect Object), and the other is what was said (the Direct Object).

Most bitransitive verbs govern the Dative Alternation. This means that the two objects can appear in two different orders, ad lib, without any meaning difference. In one variant, the Indirect Object appears with a preposition *to*; in the other the order is reversed and there is no preposition.

- **`Subject` - `Verb` - `Direct Object` - *to* `Indirect Object`**

  - *He gave the book **to** me. ~ They threw the ball **to** her. ~ They told something **to** her.*

but these are not grammatical:

- **He gave the book me.* ~ **They threw the ball her*. ~ **They told something her.*

**or**

- **`Subject` - `Verb` - `Indirect Object` - `Direct Object`**

  - *He gave me the book. ~ They threw her the ball. ~ They told her something.*

but these are not grammatical:

- **He said to me something.* ~ **He gave to me the book.* ~ **They told to her something.*

However, *say* does **not** govern the Dative Alternation (although *tell* does -- that's one of the differences between them), and therefore the first alternant is the **only** way that both objects can appear with *say*. Thus it's ungrammatical to say

- **He said me something.*

Comment: Complicated grammar. I'm not familiar with Dative Alternation, but now at least I know that it exists. Thank you for the clear and simple explanation.

Comment: It may be "lower register", but I'm not averse to saying things like ["Give it me!"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=fIppxoagxRcC&pg=PA53&dq=%22give+it+me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sSWXULjVE8ec0QXdhYC4DQ&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22give%20it%20me%22&f=false) sometimes. It doesn't really sound "ungrammatical" to me - just slightly quirky/informal.

Comment: From my reading of early British fiction, I **think** that was (and maybe still is) an idiomatic structure for BrE. The only reason I would change it to _give it to me_ is to make it AmE for idiomatic consistency in the formal academic writing I edit. If it were dialog, I wouldn't change it. It's perfectly clear English. And it doesn't give me the creepy feeling I get with _gave it to John and I_. Because no AmE speaker would normally say "Give it me!", I can't judge the register: it doesn't have one in AmE. As John Lawler's answer implies, it's not grammatical for AmE.

Comment: @BillFranke, but by the above rule, "Give it me" would mean "Give me to it", which I assume it does not. "Give it to me" would be "Give me it", which I believe is marked or ungrammatical in English, where as "Give me that" is not. I'd be interested in knowing the reason for that.

Comment: @dainichi: Yes, if language were truly rule-governed and logical, that would be true, but natural language, human language, is sometimes illogical (e.g., idioms) and isn't totally rule governed: it's not C++. The reason "**Give me that!**" is okay is that the demonstrative pronouns and personal pronouns have different usage rules. Plus: idiomaticity. All natural human languages (I don't know about Esperanto, which is an artificial human language) have such problems. I can't provide a better explanation than that. I'm sorry.

Comment: @BillFranke, oh, by googling I learned that "Give me it" is actually used (in some parts of Britain, it seems). Interesting!

Comment: @Dainichi: Interesting that it's still used. See what I mean about natural language? There are scads of rules about what we are & aren't supposed to say, but the language police can't enforce them unless they can put us in jail, fine us, or have us fired from our jobs (happens all the time these days) because of what we say & how we say it. But usually that's only when we aren't politically correct. Speaking a socially "inferior" dialect can hinder one's career & social life, however: GB Shaw's _Pygmalion_ illustrates that. Real people speak real English, not style-manual/grammar book English.

Comment: @BillFranke, I hope I didn't give you the impression that I think people should speak style-manual English, on the contrary. When I ask "why", that's because I'm interested in learning why some structures survived/emerged while others did not. I never had a prescriptivist agenda.

Comment: There really is no good answer to why some structures survived and others didn't. It's much like any other evolutionary distinction -- why so few marsupials in N. America? There are occasionally answers, but they require some real research.

Comment: @Dainichi: No, you didn't. But some folks think that. One high school English teacher when I was a kid, and one high school Chinese teacher who I met here in Taiwan about 15 years ago were so very much alike in that respect it scared me. Same tone of voice, and same stilted advice about speaking. But nothing you've said suggests anything prescriptivist.

Comment: @JohnLawler, ok, so asking "why" might be an ambitious question, as I'm well aware that not many reasons for language change are known. But I still think there are reasons, however complex they are. And learning how the language change takes its course should at least be a step in the right direction.

Comment: What about when the DO of "say" is a clause, like here, "He said to me that the drapes had caught fire"? Is it (and generally, are those sentences) ungrammatical? // And what about when the DO has a subordinate clause of its own, like here, "He said to me something I'll never forget"?

Comment: @MrReality: _Say_ is normally used to indicate the message itself (it can take a direct quotation as object, for instance), while _tell_ refers more to the content of the message (often expressed in a _that_-clause). So sentences like _?He said to me that the drapes needed cleaning_ are rare; _He told me_ is more likely with an expressed indirect object. That's one of the differences between _say_ and _tell_ -- and there are a lot more; why have two verbs if you don't want them to divide the work?

Comment: The following seems odd but grammatical to me: "When I was young, my father said to me something I have remembered my whole life." Yet "He said to me something" by itself is definitely off. What's the difference?

Comment: That's Heavy-NP Movement. The lengthy phrase _something...life_ needs to go at the end where it can be parsed more easily; and the _to me_ would sound stupid after such a long rumble. So you get _he said to me `<long NP>`_ instead.

Answer (score 4):

English is a word-order language. When the verb (**say**) is transitive (takes a direct object [DO]: "***something***" in this sentence) and the indirect object [IO] is in a prepositional phrase ("***to me***" in this sentence), the grammatically correct word order is:

> **said something to me**.

It's not standard English to say **He said me something**, but it is standard English to say **He told me something**. This suggests either that the verb in your sentence is actually a phrasal verb, (***say to***, but my Collins Cobuild *Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs* doesn't include it, nor does any Web page on phrasal verbs) or that ***say*** doesn't have the same usage rules as ***tell***.

The verb ***give*** is like ***tell*** in that respect: Both

> **He gave something to me** ~ **He told something to me**

and

> **He gave me something** ~ **He told me something**

are grammatically correct. The pattern is S+V+DO+to+IO or S+V+IO+DO.

Once you add a complement to **something**, the relative clause ***that I'll never forget***, the usage rule changes and "**said to me something (that) I'll never forget**" is grammatical and acceptable because of the desirability of placing the (reduced, i.e., minus the relative pronoun *that*) relative clause immediately after the noun phrase it modifies.

The sentence **"He came and said to me something I'll never forget"** seems to me a bit of a style problem. I'd change *said to me* to *told me* or just to *said* without the *to me*, unless context demanded *said to me*.

> **"He came and told me something I'll never forget"**
>   **"He came and said something I'll never forget"**

Ultimately, with the relative clause, it's a style and usage question. Without the relative clause, it's a grammar question (deleting the preposition *to* is necessary).

I'd also probably insert *over* between *came* and *and*.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to realize that we "say" words, but we "tell" people.  "Tell me something."  "Say something to me."

Comment: I think that is far simpler to grasp and gives an accurate result that will satisfy the OP.