# Have something to give someone or give TO someone

Tags: grammaticality

Very commonly, I have seen people use:

> I have nothing to give you.

But, why is the most common usage

> I have no advice to give **to** our viewers.

And is “I have no advice to give our viewers” wrong?

How can I know when to use **to** and when not to?

> I have only love to offer you.

Vs

> I have only love to offer to you.

Which one is correct?

Comment: _Give_ is a (perhaps **the**) bitransitive verb. It has two objects: one is something that moves, and the other is someone who receives the moving thing. These objects of bitransitive verbs can appear in either order, subject to certain constraints. One order requires the _to_, but the other order doesn't. I.e, both are correct, and which one you use is up to you, depending on which object you want to appear last. The term for this phenomenon is the [Dative Alternation](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90170/15299).

Answer (score 2):

With ditransitive verbs (verbs taking a direct and an indirect object), when both objects follow the verb we can say:

- I give you the book.

OR

- I give the book to you.

When the direct object precedes the verb (that is, in relative clauses) the indirect object may or may not take *to*:

- This is the book I want to give you.

OR

- This is the book I want to give to you.
- Here's the picture I need to show you.

OR

- Here's the picture I need to show to you.
- This is the letter I have written you.

OR

- This is the letter I have written to you.

The versions without "to" can sound more idiomatic.