# Receiver position in 'Give to'

Tags: grammar, verbs, prepositions, word-order

Can someone please tell me why it's incorrect to say:

> If you give to your child that name.

But you can say:

> If you give your child that name.

And

> If you give that name to your child,...

Comment: Why do you think the first example is incorrect?

Comment: Including 'to' in '... give [[to] recipient] [direct object (etc)] ...' is more formal, often unidiomatically so in some contexts, but still perhaps preferable when the direct object is weighty (a long string) or the structure needs gravitas.

Comment: This is an example of the [Dative Alternation](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90170/15299): _She gave the book to Bill_ alternates with _She gave Bill the book_. Both are grammatical, and mean the same thing; that's what transformations and alternations do - change the structure without changing the meaning.

Comment: If you give to your child that name.= maybe 19th c. but not today.

Answer (score 1):

Within the typical [word order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_order) in English, SVO (Subject+Verb+Object),

> an indirect object always comes before the direct object
>
> - She gave *the dog* (IO) *its dinner* (DO).

This is the order you expect *normally* and prepositions are ***not required***. Only if you reverse the order of the objects, you need to use prepositions:

> We can often rephrase such sentences with a prepositional phrase using ***to*** or ***for*** *+ the recipient*. In this case, the direct object usually comes first.
>
> - **indirect + direct object**:
>    *He always gives the class too much homework.*
>   *I never buy her flowers. She’s allergic to them.*
> - **direct object + prepositional phrase with** ***to/for***:
>     *He always gives too much homework to the class.*
>   *I never buy flowers for her. She’s allergic to them.* ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/objects))

> If you give to your child that name.

is not necessarily ungrammatical, but it is unidiomatic, especially in such a short sentence, as it was noted in the comments. Nevertheless, *you will find **to** + indirect object before the direct object* in complex sentences, for the sake of avoiding ambiguity between the two objects:

> That same spring Congress passed the National Defense Act that increased the number of personnel authorized in the Aviation Section from 60 to 148 officers and *gave* ***to the President** (IO)* ***the power to establish the enlisted strength** (DO)*. ([source](https://www.afhra.af.mil/About-Us/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/433914/the-birth-of-the-united-states-air-force/))

Comment: A lengthy DO and a need for gravitas encourage the [to NP1][DO / NP2] ordering: 'One consequence of this moral anesthesia is the belief that you are in good standing with God if you give to him what the desires of your flesh can spare.' [[Rosaria C Butterfield; Openness Unhindered; GoodReads {quote 20}](https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/6151151.Rosaria_Champagne_Butterfield)]

Comment: Agreed. I was just adding that bit in my answer while you were posting your comment.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! :)

Comment: In this: gave to the President (IO) the power to establish the enlisted strength (DO), you do not need "to" the President. It works fine without it.